# SharePoint 2010 Update view = reflects on List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

Say you have a list...a document library "**TestDoc**" and you have a standard view "**TestView1**" applied to it. You also have the same "**TestDoc**" on a diferent page ("**Page 2**") with a standard view "**TestView2**" applied to it.

Currently, if you make changes to "**TestView1**" no changes will be made to your "**TestDoc**"...Likewise, updating "**TestView2**" will not change "**TestDoc**" on "**Page 2**".

How do you attach a view to a list such that updates made to the view will be reflected on the lists that you have that view attached to?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on the Microsoft SharePoint forum and it seems that updating multiple lists upon updating a single view is not possible without tinkering with server-side code.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d2ecdbff-371b-45a5-8f3c-075bab3c29e5/list-view-auto-update-carryover